# PHP Load every class in a directory

Tags: php

I have coded a PHP script that includes every file in a directory. But im wondering if there is a way to load the classes in the files im including like a autoloader or something?

```
<?php
define("include_dir", dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/');

foreach (scandir(include_dir) as $filename) 
{
    if (is_file(include_dir . '/' . $filename)) 
    {
        //its a php file, lets do this!
        if (substr($filename, -4) == '.php')
        {
            include include_dir . $filename;
        }   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sure. Have you googled for PHP Autoloader, or did you just make that up? If the first, what have you found? If the second, try googling and you'll find [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). :)

Comment: what do you mean my load? Simply included the files should make any classes within available

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: perhaps create a extension class in each and name it LoadPlugin() or similar then execute LoadPlugin() at the end of the include loop?

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2();
```

the manual -

```
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php
```

Comment: How can you access this class? like $class->function

Comment: If you have to define a new class by yourself how is a autoloader diffrent? It just includes the file for you?